# Rulling on hadith regarding water wasting

Tags: hadith, kufr

Assalamualaikum,  last day when I was looking after my younger brother,  I found him playing with water and spilling it on to the bed , on seeing him wasting water  i took up the cup , at that time a thought came to my mind that prophet muhammad (let peace be upon him) had said  not to waste water  , I don't exactly the hadith at that time and later I searched in Google  and found this sunnah Ibn Maajah (419) narrated from ‘Abdullah ibn ‘Amr ibn al-‘Aas (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (blessing and peace of Allah be upon him) passed by Sa‘d when he was doing wudoo’, and he said, “What is this extravagance, O Sa‘d?” He said: Can there be any extravagance in wudoo’? He said, “Yes, even if you are on the bank of a flowing river.” 
As I said I don't know the  hadith at that time . But I had the thought that prophet muhammad said not to waste water in my mind.  At that time my brother was crying badly and I know if I gave the cup he would again spill it on bed and my mother would scold me,  I and whole members of my family were fasting so we are not able to drink the water.  So I spilled the water through window  outside.  I don't intent to reject hadith or do kufr.  Pls answer my question is it kufr I am getting worried and sick day by day . Pls answer it fastly .
Assalamualaikum

Comment: Please stop re-posting questions. I don't know of a hadith on wasting water it would be helpful if you shared it. Further you question title should reveal what hadith you are ignoring as is it is too generalized.

Answer (score -2):

I understand how you feel. A lot of the time I find something new that I shouldn't do and a moment later find myself doing it. You should really be conscious of what you do as a person. If it was an accidental spill, like falling over and spilling it, I doubt Allah (SWT) will hold you accountable. If it was on purpose, and he was wary of the fact that it is haram, then it would be counted.